# SailsJS how to setup Mocha Test Framework?

Tags: express, mocha.js, sails.js

I want to add tests to my SailsJS project, Mocha is pretty common so I decided to use it.

I configured and registered the grunt-mocha-test to run my tests when the "default" task trigger (tasks/register/default.js) runs, **but it is not running anything!**

**How to properly configure and setup Mocha into SailsJS to run automatically with grunt?**

**Is it possible to run the tests manually?**

Here is what I did:

**1) install test packages**
npm install mocha --save-dev
npm install grunt-mocha-test --save-dev
npm install sinon --save-dev
npm install assert --save-dev

**3) added file tasks/config/mocha-test.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('mochaTest', {
      test: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'spec'
        },
        src: ['tests/**/*.spec.js']
      }
    }),

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
};
```

**3) registered tasks in tasks/register/default.js **

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compileAssets', 'linkAssets',  'watch', 'mochaTest']);
};
```

**2) created tests folder in the app root**

tests/controller/session.spec.js

```
    var SessionController = require('../../api/controllers/SessionController'),
        sinon = require('sinon'),
        assert = require('assert');

        console.log('SessionController: ', SessionController);

    describe('The SessionController', function () {
        describe('When we load the signIn page', function () {
            it ('should render the view', function () {
                var view = sinon.spy();
                SessionController.index(null, {
                    view: view
                });
                assert.ok(view.called);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that setting up a Grunt task to run your Mocha tests is the best solution.  The Grunt tasks in the Sails "pipeline" are run every time you do `sails lift`; running your tests every time you lift the server could become very annoying as you add more tests to your suite, because you tend to do `sails lift` a lot during development!

You certainly can run the tests manually; you just need to install Mocha globally:

```
sudo npm install -g mocha
```

Then in your app's root directory, simply type `mocha` to run all the tests under `/test`.  You can specify a subset of tests to run by giving the command a subdirectory, e.g. `mocha test/controller`.

As far as the tests themselves are concerned, it's possible to unit test a controller by requiring it the way you're doing, but it means you'll have to mock up request and response objects.  A better way is to lift a Sails instance in your `before` function, and then make HTTP requests to your controllers.  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918545/sailsjs-how-to-properly-unit-test-controllers) for a couple of examples of lifting Sails from within tests, either before *every* test or before *each* test.  You can then use the Node `http` module to make requests to your controllers, or make life easier on yourself and use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module.